# Find the possible values for the common ratio, r.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ratio

The sum of the second and third terms of a geometric sequence is 96. The sum to infinity of this sequence is 500. Find the possible values for the common ratio, r.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  For an exercise such as this, you should show us what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive answers that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ar+ar^2=96$, $\frac{a}{1-r}$=500.

$ar(1+r)=96, a=500(1-r)$

$500(1-r)r(1+r)=96, r-r^3=\frac{96}{500}$
now i think you can calculate this by your own..
$r=\frac{1}{5}, \frac{\sqrt{97}-1}{10}, \frac{-\sqrt{97}-1}{10}$